# MYSQL left join (if id is in other table then 1 else 0)

Tags: mysql, if-statement, left-join

i have a table EVENT_COMMENTS and EVENT_COMMENTS_LIKES, and everything works fine except that i want to check if i liked that comment already. So i do a left join with the likes table (has foreign keys (comment_id and user_id)) and if that user_id is my own id i want to output = true.

But it is not working at all. I mean i get the list with l.User_ID of all IDs (which i count for the amount of likes) but i cannot check if my id is in there. **54** is in this case **my** id.

```
SELECT c.Comment_ID,c.Event_ID,c.User_ID,count(l.User_ID) as amount_likes,

(case l.User_ID when 54 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) as is_liked

FROM EVENT_COMMENTS c 
left join USERINFO u on u.USERID=c.User_ID
left join EVENT_COMMENTS_LIKES l on l.Comment_ID = c.Comment_ID
WHERE Event_ID=121514
GROUP BY c.Comment_ID
ORDER BY updated_time DESC
```

The bold one is the tricky one.

*`This is the error: Expression #10 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'markusp.l.User_ID' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`*

Appreciate your help :)

Comment: The error message in this particular case says it all...

Comment: You ca'n't select column not involved  in aggregation function and not mentioned in group by ...

Comment: Im so dumb, sorry for wasting your time. God this took me more than an hour :/ adding l.User_ID to group by worked it out.

Comment: @Markus I do not think that adding  l.User_ID to group by is a good idea, it changes the whole query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including all of your non-aggregate columns in your GROUP BY. In your example they would be: c.Comment_ID, c.Event_ID, c.User_ID

Comment: The OP's mysql version is a bit smarter and it does not need to list any other fields from table c in the group by that are functionally dependent on the comnent_id

Answer (score 0):

If every user can like a comnent only once, thenuse condtional counting in place of the `(case l.User_ID when 54 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) as is_liked` expression:

```
sum(l.User_ID = 54) as is_liked
```

The `l.User_ID = 54` evaluates as true or false (1 or 0), which is summed up per comment.

Since you use the aggregate function `sum()`, you will not get the error message shown in the question.

Answer (score -1):

As Shadow says, the error message contains the solution. Try unsetting the `sql_mode`

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

And re-run the query.

Comment: No, do not do this.